# I'm considering buying sound bar with bluetooth for my home theatre, can I pair my Ubuntu 14.04 system with the speakers?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, speakers

I'm currently investigating purchasing this [Sony HT-CT60BT 2.1 Channel Surround Soundbar and Subwoofer with Bluetooth/NFC Function](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00I98DHW8/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=1EI5EQ3PVJMYK&coliid=I2WU0MUZ1WK4I0). It seems a good purchase to go with my tv.

However, I'm really excited about the idea of have a speaker system with bluetooth. I'm hoping I could stream Spotify from my 14.04 laptop to these speakers by bluetooth. Is this possible with Ubuntu?

Comment: It should, does the laptop have bluetooth?

Comment: Yes it does have bluetooth. I've purchased the speaker and it works really well. I installed this sound switcher I found on OMG Ubuntu (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/sound-switcher-app-ubuntu) to change my output device quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does have bluetooth. I've purchased the speaker and it works really well. I installed this sound switcher I found on OMG Ubuntu (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/sound-switcher-app-ubuntu) to change my output device quickly.